# DataGrid: убрать границы столбца и объединить ячейки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите пожалуйста как у столбца DataGrid убрать границы и объединить ячейки?

Answer (score 1):

Переопределить Template.

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата" />
    <DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 5 0" />
              </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="Набор1" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Зн1" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Зн2" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Зн3" />
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="условие" Margin="0 0 5 0">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
              <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
          </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 5 0" />
              </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Набор2" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Зн1" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Зн2" />
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

P.S. запостил с мобилы, возможно всё криво, извиняюсь.

Comment: кхм у вас что то съехало, это не читабельно...

Comment: Ловим RowDataBound, удаляем ненужную ячейку и делает нужную растянутой на две колонки. e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(1); e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 2;

Comment: я даже не уверен что это то что мне нужно. Я просто где-то уже не помню где видел такой интерфейс красивый: таблица, при наведении на ячейку, прямо в этой ячейке справа появляется кнопка, там было кажется че то типа скопировать в буфер обмена чтоли... Вот и я хотел что то подобное сделать.

Comment: Попробуй найти образец, так легче будет тебе подсказать.